# Include Single letter in fulltext search mysql

Tags: mysql, search, indexing, full-text-search

I have a mysql backend which has the table named `device`. A column in the table `title` is where I need to search. The title column contains the names of some mobile phones. Here is a sample dataset in the table:

```
+----+----------------------+
| id | title                |
+----+----------------------+
|  1 | Apple iPhone 4       |
|  2 | Apple iPhone 4S      |
|  3 | Apple iPhone 5       |
|  4 | Apple iPhone 5S      |
|  5 | Apple iPhone 6       |
|  6 | Apple iPhone 6 Plus  |
|  7 | Apple iPhone 6S      |
|  8 | Apple iPhone 6S Plus |
+----+----------------------+
```

I created a FULLTEXT Index on this table using the following command:

```
CREATE FULLTEXT INDEX idx ON device(title);
```

When I search using the following MySQL Command:

```
SELECT title FROM device WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('iPhone 6');
```

The top result is iPhone 4.

What I've observed is that, it is ignoring the single digit at the end. If I search for `iPhone 6S`, I get the correct row at the top. But searches like `iPhone 4`, `iPhone 5`, `iPhone 6`, all result in iPhone 4 at the top. How do I solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Product names are too challenging for the simple-minded `FULLTEXT`.

Answer (score 3):

Fulltext index, and therefore search is based on words, not patterns. There is a minimum length parameter that applies to words, any word below that length is not indexed, therefore is not considered as part of the weighting of the results. A single character word (6) is probably below the limit, therefore is discarded.

What you can do:

1. Reduce the minimum length limit to 1, see [mysql's documentation on fine tuning fulltext indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html):

> The minimum and maximum lengths of words to be indexed are defined by
>   the innodb_ft_min_token_size and innodb_ft_max_token_size for InnoDB
>   search indexes, and ft_min_word_len and ft_max_word_len for MyISAM
>   ones.

Further consideration:

```
 - Fulltext indexes have to be rebuilt after this change
 - Fulltext indexes may grow extremely big with this change
```

2. Change your fulltext search to [boolean mode](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-boolean.html) and search for the exact phrase:

`SELECT title FROM device WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('"Iphone 6"' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ;`

or

`SELECT title FROM device WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('Iphone 6*' IN BOOLEAN MODE) ;`

3. Dump fulltext search and just use `like` with pattern matching.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try query

```
SELECT title FROM device WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('iPhone 6*' IN BOOLEAN MODE);
```

It should find all rows that contain words such as “iPhone 6” and “iPhone 6S”.

Answer (score 0):

I used LIKE in addition to MATCH to take advantage of FULLTEXT, but only get exact matches...

```
SELECT title FROM device WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('iPhone 6') AND title LIKE 'iPhone 6*';
```

OR you could just use LIKE to put the exact matches first

```
SELECT title FROM device WHERE MATCH (title) AGAINST ('iPhone 6') ORDER BY title LIKE 'iPhone 6*' DESC;
```